# How can I avoid the infinite loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, while-loop, fetch

Getting an infinite loop. the cursor fetches one single record for testing purposes  but it cannot leave the fetch loop. It is the first time I am using  microsoft sql. I am not sure about the syntax and the positioning of the fetch statement.
I am trying to update invoice details , that is for one invoice there are more than one items.  Please help.

```
Begin--1

        Declare     @Det_inv_cnt int,       ---------count invoice in detail
                    @Cnt_item5 int,         --------count item  number 5        
                    @Cnt_item6 int,         --------count item number 6
                    @sprice money,          --------sum vatable amt     
                    @vat_amt money,         --------vat amt 
                    @inv int,               --------invoice
                    @customer int,          --------customer id
                    @sdate datetime,        --------date
                    @edate datetime         --------date

        begin--2


                    Declare inv_id Cursor For (Select invoice from plat.dbo.iheader 
                                                Where customer in (Select id from plat.dbo.customer   
                                                                    Where custype = 1 
                                                                    and id = 2601)
                                                and invoice = 2628 
                        OPEN inv_id
                        FETCH NEXT FROM inv_id INTO @inv -----------------------------next invoice from cursor
                        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
                            BEGIN--------begin4

                                set @sprice      = 0;
                                set @vat_amt     = 0;
                                set @det_inv_cnt = 0;   
                                set @cnt_item5   = 0;
                                set @cnt_item6   = 0;
                                set @customer    = (select  customer from plat.dbo.iheader where @inv = invoice);
                                set @Det_inv_cnt = (select  count(1)
                                                    from    plat.dbo.idetail d  
                                                    where   d.item in ('2','4') 
                                                    and     d.invoice = @inv)


                                If (@Det_inv_cnt>0) ---------------------------------------end if 10

                                    Begin -----begin5 end if 10
                                    --calculate vatable amt and vat  round(0.15*sum(a.price),2)
                                        set @sprice =   (Select  sum(price)     
                                                        From plat.dbo.idetail 
                                                        Where  invoice = @inv
                                                        And item in ('2','4'));

                                         set @vat_amt = (Select  (0.15*(sum(price)))    
                                                        From plat.dbo.idetail 
                                                        Where  invoice = @inv
                                                        And item in ('2','4'));

                                        set @cnt_item5 =    (Select count(1)
                                                            From    plat.dbo.idetail 
                                                            where   item     = '5'
                                                            and     invoice  = @inv
                                                            and     customer = @customer);

                                         set @sdate =       (select  sdate  
                                                            From    idetail     
                                                            Where   item ='2'
                                                            or      item = '4'
                                                            And     invoice = @inv);

                                        set @edate =        (select edate 
                                                             From   idetail     
                                                             Where  item ='2'
                                                            or      item = '4'
                                                            And     invoice = @inv);

                                        --select details to insert new record

                                        INSERT INTO idetail
                                                ( invoice 
                                                , item 
                                                , descriptio 
                                                , qty 
                                                , price 
                                                , date 
                                                , customer 
                                                , sdate 
                                                , edate  
                                                --,timestamp
                                                ,profileid
                                                , id_item_code 
                                                , id_taxable_amt 
                                                , id_item_instock 
                                                , id_extended 
                                                , id_category_id 
                                                , id_subcategory_id 
                                                , id_rg_id 
                                                , id_svc_id 
                                                , id_sbd_id 
                                                , id_rate_id 
                                                , id_prorated )
                                        values ( @inv                           --invoice
                                                ,'TAX#1003'                         --item
                                                ,'#VAT (Rs. '+ @sprice +' x 15%)'   --descriptio
                                                ,1                                  --qty
                                                ,@vat_amt                           --price
                                                ,@sdate                                 --date
                                                ,@customer                          --customer
                                                ,@sdate                             --sdate
                                                ,@edate                             --edate
                                                --,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                                ,-1                                 --profileid
                                                ,0                                  --itemcode
                                                ,@SPRICE                            --taxable  amt
                                                ,null                               --id_item_instock, int,
                                                ,@VAT_AMT                           --id_extended, money,
                                                ,1002                               --id_category_id, int,
                                                ,0                                  --id_subcategory_id, int,
                                                ,0                                  --id_rg_id, int,
                                                ,0                                  --id_svc_id, int,
                                                ,0                                  --id_sbd_id, int,
                                                ,0                                  --id_rate_id, int,
                                                ,null);                             --id_prorated, char(1)

                                            /*From  dbo.plat.idetail    
                                            Where   item ='2'
                                            or      item = '4'
                                            And     invoice = @inv; 
                                            */


                                            Begin --11
                                            If @Cnt_item5 > 0 ------------------------------------------------------if cnt_item 5 >0
                                                Begin------6
                                                    --delete  old VAT record
                                                    Delete from idetail 
                                                    where   invoice = @inv
                                                    and     item = '5'
                                                    and     customer = @customer;


                                                    --update roundoff item number 6
                                                    set @cnt_item6 =    (Select  count(1)
                                                                        from    plat.dbo.idetail w
                                                                        where   w.invoice = @inv
                                                                        and     w.customer = @customer
                                                                        and     w.item = '6')


                                                    If @Cnt_item6>0  -------------------------------------------if cnt_item6>0
                                                        Begin---7   
                                                            update plat.dbo.idetail 
                                                            set item = '5'
                                                            where   invoice = @inv
                                                            and     customer = @customer
                                                            and     item = '6';
                                                        End;--7
                                                    Else -------------------------------------------------------------else cnt_item6
                                                        Begin--8
                                                            Insert into  err_log( 
                                                                        El_customer,
                                                                        El_Invoice,
                                                                        El_msg,
                                                                        El_date)
                                                            Values (
                                                                        @customer,
                                                                        @inv,
                                                                        ('Residential Script - Count of Item 6 returned 0'),
                                                                        getdate());
                                                        End;--8

                                                End; --end 6 of begin cnt5>0
                                            End;--11
                                --  End;---5

                                    ---update header with vat_amt

                                    Begin--9        
                                        Update plat.dbo.iheader 
                                        Set taxtotal    = @vat_amt
                                        where invoice   = @inv
                                        and customer    = @customer;
                                    end;--9
                                end;--5

                Else ----------else 10 dev_inv_cnt
                /* no item found the  insert in table*/
                begin--10
                    Insert into  err_log( 

                            El_customer,
                            El_Invoice,
                            El_msg,
                            El_date)
                    Values (
                            @customer
                            ,@inv  
                            ,('Residential - Count of Item 2 and 4 returned 0')
                            ,Getdate());
                end;--10

            --End; --------end begin 4 while 
            FETCH NEXT FROM inv_id INTO @inv --get nxt record for cursor  invt id       
            End; ----begin 4
            CLOSE inv_id;
            DEALLOCATE inv_id;
            --GO
         end;---begin 2
End;--1
```

Comment: It's entirely likely you can do this without a loop. Are you just inserting record(s) based of another record with some transformations? Just use `INSERT INTO / SELECT FROM` for that

Comment: For future reference, the SQL server tag represents Microsoft Sql. I've added it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `FETCH NEXT FROM Inv_IdINTO @invnext` instruction is within the ELSE branch of the former IF statement. It needs to be put after the ELSE branch

Answer (score 0):

You're only fetching from the cursor once and your while loop is checking the status of that fetch. Since it presumably succeeded, that condition is always evaluated as true.

For what it's worth, here's the template that I use for my cursors:

```
declare cursorName cursor fast_forward local for
    -- your select goes here

OPEN cursorName
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName INTO --variable list here
    if (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0)
        BREAK;

    -- do stuff here 

END
CLOSE cursorName
DEALLOCATE cursorName
```